# process memory search in python equivalent to Win32::Process::Memory

Tags: python, perl, debugging

[Win32::Process::Memory](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aProcess%3a%3aMemory) for Perl has a nice function to search a process's memory for arrays of uint, int, etc... Can the same be done with [pydbg](http://pedram.redhive.com/PaiMei/docs/PyDbg/) or other module for Python?

[Here](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=233563) is an autohotkey script for fetching a list of all the memory pages that can then be searched individually.  This is how the perl module works internally anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with autohotkey.
Looking throught the pydbg examples in grayhat python and looking at the source of the snapshot functions in pydbg.py, should be straightforward with python as well.